# Ember How to Run Angular Directive and How to Import Angular

Tags: angularjs, ember.js, angularjs-directive, components, file-manager

I am trying to use the angular-filemanager addon on Ember and have not been successful at all. I found this other question on stackoverflow which says how to run an angular directive inside Ember, but it didn't help much.

[Run an angular directive inside other javascript framework template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428740/run-an-angular-directive-inside-other-javascript-framework-template)

```
import Component from 'ember-component';
import angular from 'angular';

export default Component.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    debugger;
    let model = this.get('model');
    angular.module('myapp', []).directive('somedirective', function() {
        return { template: 'test {{ model[0] }} test' };
    }).run(function($rootScope){ $rootScope.model = model; });

    angular.bootstrap(this.element, ['myapp']);
  }
});
```

I installed angular with `bower install --save angular` and tried to import it like in the code above, but it doesn't work. Do I have to import it from `ember-cli-build.js` file or something like that?

Also, can someone please explain to me what this code is doing? I think it is creating an angular module which returns that template when the component is used.. so do I just call the component and it works with no template for the component? Like `{{component-name model=model}}`?

Comment: I think you need to look at https://github.com/miguelcobain/ember-paper.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to put `app.import('bower_components/angular/angular.js');` in the `ember-cli-build.js` inside `modules.exports` function. Then, I also added `"angular"` to the `predef` section of `.jshintrc` to avoid `angular not defined` error.